# load data from cursor to Listview android2.1

Tags: android, cursor

I am a new programmer. I am unable to give a start for this. I would like to populate **cFloors** to a list.

Thankyou in advance...

public class FloorsActivity extends Activity {

```
AutomationDBAccessor db = new AutomationDBAccessor(this);


private OnClickListener  floorsUpdateListener = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Cursor cFloors = db.getFloors();

        if(cFloors!=null)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "floors loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }



    }




};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.floors);


    Button btnGetFloors = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetFloors);
    btnGetFloors.setOnClickListener(floorsUpdateListener);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example on using a ListView: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

But instead of ArrayAdapter in the example, you can use a SimpleCursorAdapter for cFloors and attach it to the view using setListViewAdapter().

SimpleCursorAdapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the link http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.com/2011/11/simple-cursor-adapter-made-easy.html.
It contains all the data/code you require to build a simple cursor adapter.